# Nitrous.io/Heroku: limit updating/deleting records to the extent possible

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, nitrousio, heroku-postgres

Using: Rails 4, Nitrous.io, Heroku.

I would like to restrict, to the extent possible, my ability to update or destroy records. I scrape ephemeral data daily and my PostgreSQL database is the only copy in existence. I want to keep my data unaltered and safe from accidental/malicious deletion.

Heroku does not allow multiple PostgreSQL users (therefore solutions involving creating additional users with limited database permissions are not applicable).